# how to make a variable immutable in python

Tags: python, list

My python script:

```
N = 2  # 2*2 matrix

a = N * [0]
b = a

print(b)  # prints [0, 0]

for i in range(N):
    a[i] = N * [0]

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        a[i][j] = 0

print(a)  # prints [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

print(b)  # prints [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Why does my second `print(b)` change? How to make it immutable? I'd like my `b` to still contain `[0, 0]`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your understanding of "objects" in Python and variable assignments is flawed.

In a language like C, when you define a variable (say `int a`), a tiny area of memory is allocated and reserved for this variable and `a` is now something that refers to this area of memory. You can poke into this area, change it and find that `a` "has a" different value now. A statement like `a = 2` (or `a = b` where `b` is another variable) takes the value of the right hand side and writes it into the memory location reserved for `a`. Now you can modify `b` as you wish but `a` will still retain the original value. This is why you can do things like `a++` in C which means, "get the value of what `a` refers to, add one to it and write it back to the same location".

In Python, when you say `x = []`, a new list object is created and `x` is made to "point" to that list. Now any change you make to `x` is affecting this object. Suppose you say `y = x`, you will get another reference to the same object. Changing `y` (or `x` for that matter) 
will change the object which is now pointed to by `x` and `y`. This is what you've done with the `B = A` assignment. All things done to this object via `A` will be visible when you access it via `B` since they both point to the same object. In this sense, all variables in Python are like pointers in C. You can also understand why we don't have a `++` operator in Python since it's meaningless to modify the contents of a memory location like in C.

The solution suggested by others so far is suggesting that you make a new object with the exact same contents as the list pointed to by `A` and make `B` point to this copy. This way, if you modify `A` (or what `A` points to), `B` (or what `B` points to) will remain unchanged.

This however doesn't make `B` "immutable" (i.e. an object which cannot be modified in place). However, I think you have simply used the word erroneously and meant that you didn't want the aliasing to take place.

Comment: So there is no way to make a variable immutable in python?

Comment: If you're asking for constants (which I take to mean a binding of a value to a symbol that can't be altered) during the lifetime of the program, then no, there isn't. There are workarounds but those are just that.

Comment: I guess the "++" remark is no more relevant? It is now a valid Python operator.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś I missed that. Do you have  reference? Would love to know more.

Answer (score 20):

When assigning objects in python, you assign references (something like pointers in C).

There are several ways to circumvent this but the IMHO most idiomatic is using copy:

```
import copy
B = copy.copy(A)
```

In some cases you even may want to used deepcopy(), have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) for details.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is:

```
B=A
```

now both point to the same object.

Try:

```
B = [i for i in A]
```

now B is a new list containing all the elements from A. Or simply:

```
B = A[:]
```

Comment: you can use B = A.copy() too

Comment: What you're referring to is called shallow copy and for lists it's simply `B = list(A)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you assign `B`:

```
B = A
```

to

```
B = A[:]
```

Comment: This solution is good for arrays and only for them. It hides the problem rather than solves.